OpenRewrite doesn't update java classes in generated-sources directory
I have a project which includes automatically generated classes. My goal is to slightly update this classes (remove annotation). I decided to try OpenRewrite but the problem is only files in src/main/java picked up by OpenRewrite but not target/generated-sources.
What I've done:
Using build-helper-maven-plugin I've added target/generated-sources to source dirs.
Running rewrite:dryRun I see that my generated classes a included into the scope but they never updated. I don't know what to check else. Is it possible that source re-generation happens after files were updated by the tool and overwrites the changes?

This is a conscious decision on our part to exclude generated sources from recipe runs, as can be seen here:
https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/blob/d950f9609c5200a4e837ebe508215bed89530618/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/maven/MavenMojoProjectParser.java#L423-L428
There is no plugin option to counter this behavior. If you wish to run recipes against generated sources you might have to move them into the paths we do cover for recipe runs.
